# How do you grab a certain string of text through a link in java?

Tags: java, html

Is it possible to grab a certain piece of text through Java in a website? like for example, https://weather.com/weather/today/l/41.93,-88.25?par=google&temp=f , how would i be able to figure out the temp that it displays in java?

Comment: I think your question is about temperature, but the temp tag is about the temporary files folder and is not appropriate for your question. Similarly, I don't see anything related to debugging in your question, so the debugging tag is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The practical answer to your question is: You don't wanna do that.

Let me try to answer it, at which point you'll realize why you don't want to:

### How do I programatically parse a website?

It's complicated. Just about every browser has an option to right click and 'view source'. Presumably the number(s) you want are in here; you can parse this text to find them. It's *NOT* easy though. You'll probably be tempted to use something like a regular expression or a simple 'find me this exact string of text' trick to find what you need. It may work. But generally that means the day that this site changes the style or just does some basic updates, your code ceases to work.

You'll need to put in your agenda to check, every day if you have to, if your code still works. That's 5 minutes out of your day, every day, for the rest of the life of this project. That sounds incredulously expensive, which is why **you don't want this**.

If you must, there are ways to tighten up your parsing code. If you use libraries like [jsoup](https://jsoup.org), that helps a bit. If you toss the entire site through a 'browser emulator', you can deal with javascript making ajax requests and the like (these days websites are like little programs, and to truly observe programmatically what the site shows to human eyes, you need to run that program to get the job done. If you're very lucky, you can inspect the 'source code' of the little program and that's all you need, but you're not always that lucky).

But, as I said, that just helps *a bit*. The day will come the weather channel changes their site and breaks your code. They won't announce it. It is not considered immoral or technically dubious to do so. Maybe you can update your agenda to check if your code works down to once a week instead of daily, but it'll be a permanent maintenance burden. **You DO NOT WANT THIS**.

### Okay, forget that. How does this really work?

Sites that are designed to let you read this stuff have an API. They'll document it someplace. This is a 'website' made specifically for code. It has no formatting, and a well defined specification. Send it this specific simple string, and this specific simple answer comes out, and the site has tooling to let you know when they change it (for example, an 'API version') - all luxuries the site meant for human consumption will not have.

You're in luck. The weather channel [has an API](https://weather.com/swagger-docs/call-for-code).

What you really want, is to read all that, figure out how that API works, and use that.

The API will not break when the weather channel decides that today is a good day to slightly change the shade of the background image.

Comment: I'm not too good at using an API and i saw you mentioned jsoup, what is it in general? ive been looking around and didnt really give me a straight forward answer, but i saw you also said about the 'find me this exact string of text' trick, is it possible to grab the '°' symbol and get the rest of the 3 text before it?

Comment: My long missive explains precisely why this is difficult and a bad idea. If you can't quite follow it, then perhaps this project is a nice goal to strive towards; your current coding skills aren't quite up to snuff for this project, but now you have something to work towards!